# Android coding error

Tags: android

i am begineer for android/java programming. my below program crashes in line

`currkm = (Double.parseDouble(currentkm.getText().toString()));`. i tried to resolve this but couldnt. I belive its a basic coding error in android.
provide your suggestion to resolve this issue.

```
package com.example.my2app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    double vehiclemileage;
    TextView mileage;
    SharedPreferences somedata;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    TextView previouskm;
    EditText currentkm;
    EditText petrollitrs;
    double currkm;
    double prevkm;
    double petrollt;
    Button resultbtn;
    String previouskmstr;
    String prevkmstring;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.mileagecalc);
                somedata= this.getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences("sakthivel",0);
                editor = somedata.edit();

                previouskm = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.previouskm);
                currentkm = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.currentkm);
                petrollitrs = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.petroLtr);
                mileage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mileage);

                previouskmstr = somedata.getString("previousmileage", null);
                previouskm.setText(previouskmstr);

                resultbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

                resultbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View arg0) {

                          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                          try{
                          currkm = (Double.parseDouble(currentkm.getText().toString()));
                          prevkm = (Double.parseDouble(previouskm.getText().toString()));
                          petrollt = (Double.parseDouble(petrollitrs.getText().toString()));
                          vehiclemileage = (currkm-prevkm)/petrollt;
                          prevkmstring = currentkm.getText().toString();
                          mileage.setText("your vehicle mileage is " + vehiclemileage);
                          editor.putString("previousmileage", prevkmstring);
                          editor.commit();
                          previouskm.setText(prevkmstring);
                          }
                          catch(NumberFormatException e){
                              e.printStackTrace();

                          }

                    }
                });
            }
}
```

log cat:

```
11-13 12:52:27.671: E/JavaBinder(661): *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
11-13 12:52:27.671: E/JavaBinder(661): java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.DeadObjectException
11-13 12:52:27.671: E/JavaBinder(661):  at android.os.Parcel.writeException(Parcel.java:1332)
11-13 12:52:27.671: E/JavaBinder(661):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:391)
```

Comment: Can you post your logcat error message

Comment: And your mileagecalc.xml layout file.

Comment: What text is there in `currkm` edittext?

Answer (score 5):

some of possibility:

I assume that you have set your input type as number only , if not then try it ,

```
edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
```

or from `XML` you can add `android:inputType="number|decimal"` inside your EditText.

It will throw you `java.lang.NumberFormatException:` and this will Thrown to indicate that the application has attempted to convert a string to one of the numeric types, but that the string does not have the appropriate format.

So, you can't parse or cast string to double if you are trying  that. otherwise syntactically your code is okay.

If you are getting force close then write your code inside `try {} & catch(exception e){}`. that will ignore your error and will not close your app.

Comment: hi,already defined the input type as "inputDecimal". Still i am getting this issue. pasted below the logcat

Comment: You are getting [Uncaught remote exception](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/RemoteException.html) & that is due to your your preference code. try [this](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/content/android-sharedpreferences-example/)